# Strange kinematics result

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

I'm currently doing some algebra-based physics problem sets and have come across this strange result.

**Problem**
A ball is tossed upwards with an initial velocity $\vec{v}_0 = 48.9\text{ m/s}$. Assuming no air resistance, the ball has a maximum height of 122 meters. How long does it take the ball to reach its maximum height?

**Attempt at a Solution**
Using the kinematics equation
$$\vec{v}_f = \vec{v}_0 - g\Delta t$$
we get the correct result of 4.98 seconds. However, if we were to use the following kinematics equation
$$\Delta\vec{y} = v_0\Delta t -\frac{1}{2}g\Delta t^2$$
which results in the following quadratic equation
$$-4.91t_f^2 + 48.9t_f -122 = 0$$
we would get complex roots for $t_f$. Any insight on this would be helpful.

Comment: No, you get real roots. Check your algebra.

Comment: Calculating the discriminant 48.9^2-4(-4.91*-122) gives -4.87, i.e., two complex roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(assuming $g$=9.81)

It's a rounding error: the ball only reaches 121.88m, so never reaches 122, so there's no real solution for the time it reaches 122.

If you look for the time it reaches 121m, you get real solutions. At the exact maximum height it's only there for one instant of time, so the determinant of the quadratic will be zero, with a single real repeated root (equal to $-b/2a$ using the normal convention)